# Why custom QWidget from another py file doens't show in a QMainWindow?

Tags: python, pyqt6

I'd like to put QWidget in a separate file.
This is custom QWidget in a separate file:

```
class Popup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
```

It is child of QWidget and it takes a parent as a function argument.
This is where I create it:

```
        # This don't work
        self.popup = Popup(self) # Popup from another file
        self.popup.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.popup.setStyleSheet("background: #000000")
        self.popup.show()
```

I should see it as black square 200x200 but I don't see it. If I don't use Popup class and just create QWidget, black square will be showed in the window.

```
        # This works
        self.popup = QWidget(self)
        self.popup.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.popup.setStyleSheet("background: #000000")
        self.popup.show()
```

So I did something wrong with passing parent to Popup class. What did I wrong?

Comment: `self.popup.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_StyledBackground, True)`.